# Style each $row at once?

Tags: php, mysql, css, pdo

My current project I am working on I am echoing every single user that  is not an administrator already in my 'administrator system' for the users that are admin_level 2 so that they can make regular users administrators and it'll update the database upon changing their level.

Currently it looks like the following echoing the user(s):

```
// users
$sth2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, username, email, admin_level FROM users WHERE admin_level < 1");
$sth2->execute();
$users = $sth2->fetchAll();
// echo users
if ($result > 1) {
  echo "<div class='col-md-6'>";
  echo "<p class='title'>Admin Level 2 Panel</p>";
  echo "<p class='title2'>Make users administrators in this module.</p>";
  echo "<table class='users' border='1'>";
  echo "<tr style='font-weight:bold;color:white;'>";
  echo "<td class='titles'>ID</td>";
  echo "<td class='titles'>Username</td>";
  echo "<td class='titles'>Email</td>";
  echo "<td class='titles'>Admin Level</td>";
  echo "<td class='titles'>New Level</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  foreach ($users as $row) {
    echo '<center>';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td class="info">' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="info">' . $row['username'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="info">' . $row['email'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="info">' . $row['admin_level'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="info2"><a href="#">1</a><a href="#">2</a></td>'; 
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</center>';
        echo '</table>';
    }
  echo "</div>";
}
```

The following is the CSS that I am using to style the table / users:

```
table.users{border-collapse:collapse;border-color:silver;text-align:center;width:100%;}
td.titles,td.info{padding:1px;color:white;}
td.info2>a{margin:0 10px;}
```

The problem I am running into here is it is styling the first user ($row) fine but every other one after that is not being effected by any of the css as you can see in the screenshot here:

[image]

Comment: you are closing your table on every loop with `</table>`you should do it after the `foreach`, so just move it to after the cycle

Comment: Margins won't work on inline elements such `<a>` as well.

Comment: And this `<center>` tag there is pointless.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just explaining my comment here:

> You are closing your table on every loop with `</table>`you should do it
>   after the foreach, so just move it to after the cycle

```
    ...
    echo "<table>";
    ...
    foreach ($users as $row) {
        echo '<center>';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td class="info">' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="info">' . $row['username'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="info">' . $row['email'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="info">' . $row['admin_level'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="info2"><a href="#">1</a><a href="#">2</a></td>'; 
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</center>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
```

---

As @HenriqueBarcelos said the `<center>...</center>` tags are irrelevant.

Comment: I'd remove that `<center>` tag too.